# UITextfields returning null in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I just updated my dev system for iOS 6 and when I was testing a app I built I am now just getting (null) from my UITextfields.

Here is a example of what I am doing: `NSString *email = usernameField.text;`

After typing in that textfield and returning what I typed I only get (null)

What am I missing with iOS 6 here?

Comment: That code should still work in iOS 6 - nothing about that API changed. Can you provide some more code around this? What method are you calling this in? How is your UITextField set up?

Comment: Add this statement:  NSLog(@"the textField=%@ text=%@", usernameField, usernameField.text);  Almost certain you'll get null null.  Probably due to a disconnected outlet.

Comment: Also, 29% acceptance might make it tougher for you to get answers here.

Comment: NSString *email = [usernameField.text copy];  try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot to synthesize the textfields for that view. They worked fine without it before but iOS 6 seems to be stricter with it.